# Can't figure out why my method isn't executing

Tags: java, if-statement, methods

Below is a snippet of code from a class in a simple program I'm writing that plays a simple game of Blackjack. **I don't understand why the hit method isn't executing whenever, upon execution of the program, I enter "hit".** It goes to the else part of the statement every time regardless of what I enter. I even added a System.out.println statement to make sure that the strings matched. I feel like I must be making a very basic mistake but I just can't seem to figure it out.

```
System.out.println("Would you like to hit or stand?");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String playerDecision = input.nextLine();
    //System.out.println(playerDecision);

    if(playerDecision == "hit") {
        hit();
    }
    else { System.out.println("ERROR");

    }

}

public void hit(){
    player.makeHand(deck.draw());
    System.out.println("You have the following  cards: ");
    player.getHand();
    System.out.println("Your hand total is ");
    System.out.println(player.findHandTotal());
```

}

Comment: You need to use the `equals` method when comparing two strings.

Comment: String comparison should be with equals method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong string comparison.  Try

```
if("hit".equals(playerDecision)) {
```